# Mabox Outdoors custom style with Mapnik

Tags: maps, tiles, mapbox, mapnik

I am trying to set up a tile server with Mapnik, renderd, mod_tile and with MapBox Outdoors style. I've been able to successfully go through https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/ tutorial and set up the server with OSM-Bright style.

Next I changed renderd.conf file and pointed the 'XML' property the 'project.xml' file from MapBox Outdoors style which I previously downloaded from Github. I've also cleared the cache, restarted renderd and apache but the new style does not work - there are only empty tiles rendered.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? What is the proper way to apply Outdoors style?

Answer (score 0):

The Mapbox Outdoors style is not compatible with the OSM Bright process described by switch2osm. It is designed to be uploaded to a Mapbox account, not to be used with a custom mod_tile setup. The style as-is relies on data in the form of vector tiles served from the Mapbox API (which requires an account / API key and is subject to certain conditions).

It would be possible to modify the source code to work with a custom database for you to use it in your own tile server setup, but you would need to make sure your layer definitions are compatible with the descriptions at https://www.mapbox.com/developers/vector-tiles/mapbox-streets/ and https://www.mapbox.com/developers/vector-tiles/mapbox-terrain/.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the second part of your answer. Looking at layers descriptions for MapBox Streets and Terrain styles it's not exactly clear for me how to make over these styles to work with a custom tile server - its styles identifiers seem to be prepared only for vector tiles, not for mapnik, mod_tile. How is it possible to relate them with i.e. style deliverd for OSM Bright? And if it's not possible what you exacly mean by modyfing the source code (which source code?) and making compatibile layer definitions?